# Read all data from the networkstream

Tags: asp.net, sockets

I need to make  a way for my users to download the mp3s files from my mp3 archive server

I have 2 servers in my network, the first server is a (web server) and the other server is used for sound tracks in mp3 formats, which I call it (sound tack server).

I need to let users to download sound files from sound track server. For this porpose I am using socket programing.

What I have done so far is that the sound files are read from sound track server and sent to webserver via networkstream. But the size of each sound track sould be known before it is simulated on the web server.

This is becuse not only the user should know the size of sound track but also the software should also undrestand the size of the sound track befor simulation can happen on the web server.

Particularly I have difficulties in the following codes regarding the aboved problem.

```
...
ns = tcpClient.GetStream()
dim recBytes( **?** ) as byte         
'By puting question mark I  am trying to show exactly where I have problem.

ns.read(recBytes,0,recBytes.lentgh)
....
Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
...
response.BinaryWrite(recBytes)
...
```

Thank you for advice

Answer (score 0):

Here recBytes( ? ) refers to the buffer that you will use to read the stream, it can be anything, if you pick too small a figure than the performance will suffer, too large and you will run out of memory. Other than that there are no restrictions. For standard network communications few K will be enough (4096 is as good as any other number).

BTW: you don't need to open separate stream from web server to your "sound tracks" (media) server, just map network path and add virtual directory mapping to your web server, then the clients will be able to access these files directly.